# Zend Framework Bootstrapping Questions

Tags: zend-framework, bootstrapping

When I do a return in an `_init*()` function in my bootstrap what does it actually do? so that I can do say a:

```
$x = $this->bootstrap('something');
```

Oh or is it so that I can do a `$this->getResource('something')`. if I do not do a return I cannot get the resource later?

Also, when I do a `$x = $this->bootstrap('something');` I guess that will be before `bootstrap()` automatically runs? When is that?

When I do a `$x = $application->getOption('something');` I am getting the 'something' array from the config? Do I actually need to do a `$application->getBootstrap()->bootstrap('something')` first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x = $this->getResource('something');
its used to  Initialize and retrieve a  "something" resource so you can use that resource else where in the app

```
$x = $this->bootstrap('something');
```

is used to to bootstrap the 'something' resource like DB , View ...etc 
in other words [to ensure that the something  resource is initialized]

while

```
$x = $application->getOption('something');
```

is used to read the config file of the 'something' resource 
it should be like

```
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"
```

highly recommend you to check the [quick start](http://framework.zend.com/docs/quickstart/create-a-model-and-database-table)